# Upgrade error from v4.5.8 to 4.6.11

Tags: upgrade

There is an upgrade error from v4.5.8 to v4.6.11. Even i tried to upgrade to v4.6.0, it fails. Please suggest an solution how to fix it. I upgrade the existing database from v4.5.5 to 4.5.8 which is running without errors.

[image: step2]

[image: Step3]

Comment: can you check if you have an option_group named `account_relationship` in your prev DB ? seems the first error gets generated due to this.

Comment: @jitendrapurohit - Thanks Jitendra, but i did not find this option group in DB which upgraded to to civicrm 4.5.8. Do you mean to find it in in previous db which was with civicrm 4.5.5.

Comment: @jitendrapurohit - I also check previous DB but not found this option_group

Answer (score 1):

Jitendra's comment is correct - it should be posted as an answer!

As for your second error, that's caused by skipping the first error.  The SQL for 4.6.alpha1 includes the command to create the "civicrm_recurring_entity" table.  When you skip the rest of the 4.6.alpha1 SQL, you're creating the circumstance that leads to the second error.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But as said by Jitendra, i did not found option group. Can you suggest how to overcome first error.